# DataBase for reporting and analyze in Pentaho

Tags: database, reporting, pentaho

I'm currently  on a project where I have to implement a BI solution. I'm going to use Pentaho suite and saiku.

After I extract and transform my data with PDI I'll put them in a MySQL DB.

My question is, do I use the same DB for reports and analyze?
And should this/these DB be a star schema?
I know that for analyze and saiku it has to be a star schema but im wondering if it's the same for the reporting part.

Thks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reporting part doesnt really matter because the queries are just normal SQL queries. However for sanity I would just build one database, and you're right it's going to have to be a star schema.  If you have 2 databases you'll end up with syncing problems and all sorts - and there's nothing worse than a BI system that is not trusted by its users because the data is inconsistent.

Also; In your reports you can use MDX too as well as SQL - so that makes things easier.

Comment: ok well that was what I think so it's fine, now the hardest part is coming, modelling and working with the ETL part :(